# Prove Descartes' Rule of Signs for a Polynomial of a Specific Degree

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to prove Descarte's rule of signs for polynomials of a specific degree. essentially i'm trying to prove that the rule of signs is true for polynomials of the form: $ ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e $ Where a, b, c, d, and e are some arbitrary coefficient.

Based on the fundamental theorem of algebra we know that said polynomial must have 4 roots: therefore there are 5 cases in which I need to prove Descarte's rule of signs:
case 1: The polynomial has 0 positive roots
case 2: The polynomial has 1 positive root
case 3: the polynomial has 2 positive roots
case 4: the polynomial has 3 positive roots
case 5: the polynomial has 4 positive roots

Now I essentially want to show a case of my polynomial where it has for sure the amount of positive  roots for each case and also has the correct amount of sign changes as per the rule of signs.

The problem is I don't know how to approach this problem past this point.

Comment: Are you also considering the cases of complex conjugate pairs as roots?

Comment: Also, when you say a,b,c,d,e are arbitrary, do you mean arbitrary reals or arbitrary complex numbers? The polynomial is only guaranteed to have 4 complex zeros; it need not have four real zeros.

Comment: aren't those implicitly included in my cases? ie. If there are 0 positive roots there must be 4 negative or complex roots because of the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: For the a,b,c,d,e part I'm not sure. I just wrote out a generic polynomial of degree 4 as I need to prove the rule of signs for ALL polynomials of degree 4

Comment: Well I mean each complex conjugate pair corresponds to a quadratic with no zeros, which either is always positive or always negative, irrespective of the input value.

Comment: It probably would be easiest to prove it for the cases n=1,2, and then use induction. Remember that you can assume without loss of generality that a=1 and that e $\not=$ 0.

Comment: by n do you mean the degree? like, prove it's true for degree 1 and 2 and then use induction?

Comment: yes prove it for linear polynomials and quadratics first (because of the real coefficients, hence complex conjugate pairs, you have to include quadratics in your base case) -> induction